# PHP, While loop not showing results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am new to PHP and mysql, I am trying to build a table. However, I have a very interesting bug that i can't fix.

code:

```
//Initializing mysql queries
//-----------------------SELECTING GOALS------------
$sql= "SELECT * FROM goals"; 
$records = mysql_query($sql);
//-----------------------SELECTING SERVICES---------
$sql2= "SELECT * FROM services";
$records2 = mysql_query($sql2);

//----------------SELECTING THE JUNCTION----------
$sql3 = "SELECT services.sid AS sid, services.name, objectives.oid
FROM services, objectives, servo
WHERE servo.s_id = services.id AND servo.obj_id = objectives.id";
$records3 = mysql_query($sql3);

$sql4 = "SELECT oid, gid, statement, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT gid) AS GOID
FROM goals, objectives, obgoals
WHERE obgoals.go_id = goals.id AND obgoals.ob_id = objectives.id
GROUP BY oid";
    $records4 = mysql_query($sql4);

<?php
while ($product = mysql_fetch_assoc($records2)) {

    echo "<tr>";

    $sid = $product['sid'];
    $service = $product['name'];
    echo "<td><a href='objectives.php?sid=" . $sid . "&service=" . $service .                       "'>" . $product['sid'] . "</a> </td>";

    echo "<td>".$product['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>";


    while ($g4services = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) { 
        echo $g4services['gid'];
    }
echo"</td>" ;
}

?>
```

Basically, my table has 30 rows and 3 columns, the last column is supposed to print out values from a database, this part is done by this piece of code

```
while ($g4services = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) { 
            echo $g4services['gid'];
        }
```

However, instead of printing the results for each row, it only prints the results for the first row, basically the first while loop runs and creates the the table with the 30 rows, but the second while loop only prints values on first row only. Essentially this is happening:

```
|SID|Name Of Service| Objectives|
 -------------------------------
|S1| Service 1      | make the best cars|
|s2| Service 2      |                   |
|s3| Service 3      |                   |
|s4| Service 5      |                   |
|s5| Service 5      |                   |
.....
.....
....
|s30| Service30     |                   |
```

for some reason, my objectives column is not populated by the while loop, it only works for the first row. If someone can help me work the while loop to print the values for every row, it will be huge help. I will greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: how do you init `$records`?

Comment: Check `$records` on each iteration.

Comment: The first iteration of the outer loop will read all the rows of the second query. The remaining iterations won't have anything left in `$records2`.

Comment: show both your queries please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're reading all the results of `$records` during the first iteration of the outer `while` loop. On future iterations, there are no more rows left, so the inner `while` loop completes immediately.

You can read those results once into a variable outside the loop, and then show that variable during the loop:

```
$all_g4services = '';
while ($g4services = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
    $all_g4services .= $g4services['gid'];
}

while ($product = mysql_fetch_assoc($records2)) {

    echo "<tr>";

    $sid = $product['sid'];
    $service = $product['name'];
    echo "<td><a href='objectives.php?sid=" . $sid . "&service=" . $service .                       "'>" . $product['sid'] . "</a> </td>";

    echo "<td>".$product['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>$all_g4services;</td>" ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. so I thought that the inner while loop would re-read the results of records again since the outer loop is calling it again.

Answer (score 0):

Your second while loop is not required.  It is runnning for each row.  Remove it.  Then for each row you have to find the entry that matches and echo only that.

```
 echo $g4services['gid']
```

I dont know how to correct it for you as I dont know the relationship between the two.